# Can't insert data into sqlite in android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I try to insert data from EditView into Sqlite but it can't insert, then close the program. My condition code is working if I don't enter any value all the edittext. After I fill all the fields and click button insert, it doesn't work. Any mistakes in my insert code?

Below is my java code

```
public class FormPage extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

public EditText KhId, Fname, Lname, sex, dob, address;
private Button btnadd, btnview, btnupdate;
SQLiteDatabase db;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.form_page);

    KhId = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    Fname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    Lname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    sex = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    dob = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText5);
    address = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText6);
    btnadd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
    btnview = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button6);
    btnupdate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button7);

    btnadd.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnview.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnupdate.setOnClickListener(this);

    db = openOrCreateDatabase("UserInfo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user(kh_id int primary key, fname varchar, lname varchar, sex varchar, dob date, address varchar)");
}

public void onClick(View view){
    if (view == btnadd) {
        if (KhId.getText().toString().equals("0")) {
            showMessage("Error", "Zero is invalid for" + " input to database");
        } else {
            if (KhId.getText().toString().equals("") || Fname.getText().toString().equals("") || Lname.getText().toString().equals("") ||
                    sex.getText().toString().equals("") || dob.getText().toString().equals("") || address.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                showMessage("Error", "Please enter all values");
                return;
            }
            Cursor c = db.rawQuery("Select kh_id From user " + "where kh_id='" +
                    KhId.getText().toString() + "'", null);

            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                showMessage("Error", "Record already exists");
                clearText();
            } else {
                db.execSQL("INSERT INTO user VALUES(" + KhId.getText() + ",'" + Fname.getText() + "','" + Lname.getText()+"','"+ sex.getText()+"','"+
                        dob.getText() + "'," + address.getText() + ");");
                showMessage("Successful", "Record added");
                clearText();
            }
        }
    }
}
 private void showMessage(String title, String msg) {
  // code
 } 
 public void Clear() {
  // code
 }
```

Comment: Do you get any error in logs when you try to insert?

Comment: do not like this i will give a good solution if you want? and also in insert query not write only gettext write gettext.tostring

Comment: @kevanaghera please.

Comment: first try in insert query write when get a value gettext.tostring().

Comment: You're a hero, @kevanaghera -- there's just so much wrong with the code above, I don't know where to begin. Thanks for taking the time to help the OP.

Comment: @kevanaghera, I don't understand. Can you give an example?

Comment: don't insert your data like this first making a new class for do a operation with database and declare all method in class and just use this method in your activity or fragment

Comment: @323go ya i know very well.

Comment: What happens when you run your code? Is there an error? How do you know that you can't insert?

Comment: @kapsym No error message in log.

Comment: @PhearumChheang First change your db.execSQL statement to db.execSQL("INSERT INTO user VALUES(" + KhId.getText().tostring()+ ",'" + Fname.getText().tostring() + "','" + Lname.getText().tostring()+"','"+ sex.getText()+"','"+ dob.getText().tostring() + "'," + address.getText().tostring() + ");");

Comment: Note that your code is susceptible to SQL injection.

Comment: If that works out. You need to change a lot more things. Right now your code is just meant to get the work done some how. I guess you followed the simplifiedcoding site. But it doesn't have the right architecture. Ideally all your DB operations should go in a helper class in seperate methods for each operation. And then you can call the helper class from your activity and pass the data to insert

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`ContentValue`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentValues.html) class to insert data into table. This will also prevent from [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Also you need to use [`insert()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues)) in `SQLiteDatabase`.

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(COL_2, KhId.getText().toString());
values.put(COL_3, Fname.getText().toString());
values.put(COL_4, Lname.getText().toString());
values.put(COL_5, sex.getText().toString());
values.put(COL_6, dob.getText().toString());
values.put(COL_7, address.getText().toString());

long res = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
```

Lastly, keep remember to use proper [naming conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)).

Comment: `"Some string" + someVariable` automagically calls `toString()`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice yes you are right, this is String concatenation know..I am editing..

Comment: This is definitely a better suggestion than your previous answer. I am not sure if it will solve the original problem.

Comment: @PhearumChheang Remove this line: `db.execSQL("INSERT INTO user VALUES(" + KhId.getText() + ",'" + Fname.getText() + "','" + Lname.getText()+"','"+ sex.getText()+"','"+
                        dob.getText() + "'," + address.getText() + ");");` and add my solution changing `TABLE_NAME`, `COL_2`, `COL_3` and etc to match with your table name and columns.

Answer (score -2):

```
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO user VALUES(" + KhId.getText().tostring()+ ",'" + Fname.getText().tostring() + "','" + Lname.getText().tostring()+"','"+ sex.getText().tostring()+"','"+
                        dob.getText().tostring() + "'," + address.getText().tostring() + ");");
```

Comment: please try to describe your solution not just adding code